# Find intersection between plane and line

Tags: python, numpy, math, geometry, intersection

I tried to find an equivalent but I am struggling to find a solution to my problems.
I have two curves defined as 2D lists in python. I want to find the orthogonal projection of the curve_1 to the curve_2.
I started something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def unit_tangent_vector(curve):
    tangent_vectors = np.diff(curve,axis=0)
    unit_tangent_vectors = tangent_vectors / np.linalg.norm(tangent_vectors,axis=1)[:,None]
    return unit_tangent_vectors

curve_1 = np.array([[   0. ,1050.45881  ]
 [  54.4012659,1050.45924  ]
 [ 108.772202  ,1050.46115  ]
 [ 163.063568  ,1050.46476  ]
 [ 217.210682  ,1050.47023  ]
 [ 271.123361  ,1050.47781  ]
 [ 324.675052  ,1050.48779  ]
 [ 377.692745  ,1050.50048  ]
 [ 427.845685  ,1053.07373  ]
 [ 461.323846  ,1068.71938  ]
 [ 494.723661  ,1084.33569  ]])
curve_2 = np.array([[   0.,        1050.56801  ]
 [  51.8993183 ,1050.56801  ]
 [ 103.798637  ,1050.56801  ]
 [ 155.697955  ,1050.56801  ]
 [ 207.597273  ,1050.56801  ]
 [ 259.496592  ,1050.56801  ]
 [ 311.39591   ,1050.56801  ]
 [ 363.295228  ,1050.56801  ]
 [ 415.191677  ,1050.56813  ]
 [ 455.961611  ,1065.59296  ]
 [ 495.02527   ,1083.69965  ]])

curve_1_tangents = unit_tangent_vector(curve_1)
curve_1_tangents = np.vstack([curve_1_tangents,curve_1_tangents[-1]]) # Need to have the same number of values as the curve
curve_2_tangents = unit_tangent_vector(curve_2)
curve_2_tangents = np.vstack([curve_2_tangents,curve_2_tangents[-1]])

ndots = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', curve_1_tangents, curve_2_tangents)

w_vector = curve_2 - curve_1


si = -np.array([t_le.dot(w) for t_le, w in zip(curve_1, w_vector)]) / ndots

psi = w_vector + si[:,None]*curve_2_tangents+curve_1 # Intersections


ax = plt.figure().gca()

ax.plot(curve_1.T[0],curve_1.T[1],marker="o",color="blue")
ax.plot(curve_2.T[0], curve_2.T[1], color="red")
ax.scatter(psi.T[0], psi.T[1], marker="x", color="green")
n = 8
ax.quiver(curve_1[n][0], curve_1[n][1], curve_1_tangents[n][0], curve_1_tangents[n][1],color="grey")
ax.quiver(curve_2[n][0],curve_2[n][1],curve_2_tangents[n][0],curve_2_tangents[n][1])
plt.show()
```

However the tangent calculation doesnt seem to be right and leads to wrong result. For example, if I run this code, It will give me:
[image]

I should have the intersection points in cyan.
Lets say, the grey tangent vector is the normal of a plane. I want to find intersections between each planes (at all points of the blue curve) and the red curve. I am not looking for intersections between the two curves.

Basically, this function works for just one plane and a line:

```
def find_intersection(plane_normal,plane_point,ray_direction,ray_point):
epsilon=1e-6
ndotu = plane_normal.dot(ray_direction) 

if abs(ndotu) < epsilon:
    print ("no intersection or line is within plane")

    w = ray_point - plane_point
    si = -plane_normal.dot(w) / ndotu
    Psi = w + si * ray_direction + plane_point #intersections
```

I just want to extend it to a numpy array containing several points

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking and how to interpret your drawing. You have placed the cyan markings at positions where there is no intersection, only slightly next to them.

Comment: And what does this have to do with a plane, or a projection, when you want to calculate the intersection between the red and the blue lines?

Comment: Lets say, the grey tangent vector is the normal of a plane. I want to find intersections between each planes and the red curve. I am not looking for intersections between the two curves.

Comment: Can you solve a simpler problem? Given a plane (defined by the normal and a point in the plane) and a single line segment, can you find the intersection point (if there is one)?

Comment: It seems to work fine on the left of the curve. As you can see the green points on the red curve are perpendicular to the tangent of the blue curve

Comment: What do you call the projection of a curve to another curve ? As far as I know, the projection is just the second curve (or part of it).